# VUEJS - Unknown custom element: <category-edit> - did you register the component correctly?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-component

I have declared my components in **app.js** like so:

```
window.Vue = require('vue');
import ExampleComponent from "./components/ExampleComponent";

new Vue({
 el: '#app',
   components:{
    'example':ExampleComponent
  }
});
```

ExampleComponent from **Laravel**

```
 <template>
   <div class="container">
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header">Example Component</div>

                        <div class="card-body">
                            I'm an example component.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>

    <script>
        export default {
            name:'example',
            mounted() {
                console.log('Component mounted.')
            }
        }
    </script>
```

The component have the option "name" too.
But I still have the error message in title
[error_message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIEUn.png)

The error I have:

```
app.js:158231 [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <example> - did you 
register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to 
provide the "name" option.(found in <Root>)
```

And the weird part of this, is the component is displayed normally.
I'm new to **vuejs** and probably missing out something.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you show the template which triggers an error? Also, please do post image for the error messages but copy the error in a code block

Comment: It's complaining about a different component than you've posted. Please show the code where you've used the component for which the error is shown.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome.
And no it's the same component. I just use a short name. Also As I said the component itself does work(displayed) even with the error. Which I'm trying to figure out.

Can it be generated if the app has many "Roots" ? By using the Vue plugin (chrome) I have 2 Roots.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
window.Vue = require('vue');
import ExampleComponent from "./components/ExampleComponent";

new Vue({
 el: '#app',
   components:{
    ExampleComponent
  }
});
```

In your html use whatever name you have used while writing the ExampleComponent like below :

```
<example-component></example-component>
```